# FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 8: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

New to laravel and I am trying to setup the user auth.  I am using laravel 5.1 so I had to add

```
"bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master"
```

to composer.json

also in my composer.json

```
  "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "TestApp\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

This lets me bring up the register and login pages at /auth/login , /auth/register.

When I complete register it throws back

```
FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 8:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

in HomeController.php line 8
```

I have also named my app using

```
php artisan app:name TestApp
```

The user details are stored correctly in the db, then when I navigate anywhere on the site it throws the error because im assuming its recognised the session.

I haven't strayed far from guides and this is a simple setup, not sure why its not working.

I am not sure where the "HomeController" is but the default controller in my dir is Controller.php and contains

```
namespace TestApp\Http\Controllers;

use TestApp\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

The Dir structure is as follows

[image: Dir structure]

Comment: can you please update your question with directory structure of controllers folder and code of `HomeController`, `use` statements to be specific?`

Comment: as you changed your app name your application namespace is now TestApp, so  you should replace App to TestApp every where it is referenced, for this error i think in your HomeController change your `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller` to `use TestApp\Http\Controllers\Controller`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change your app name your application namespace is also changed , so your application namespace is right now TestApp. so in your HomeController file change your use statement , its still using previous namespace , you should use

```
use TestApp\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Comment: Seems my namespace is ok, I have that in the Controller.php and AuthController.php.

Comment: This was the issue.  I was looking for the error in the controllers directory but didn't realise there was one in vendors folder.  Thankyou very much!